# How can I sort values by descending

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a csv file with hosts' ids and ips like this inside

```
                  Ip    Id1    Id2  Id3  Id4
0         10.10.8.30  18156  10782  NaN  NaN
1       10.10.12.113  10398  18177  NaN  NaN
2        10.10.6.111  10496  18140  NaN  NaN
3         10.10.6.97  18093  10870  NaN  NaN
4         10.10.6.63  10848  18965  NaN  NaN
```

I whant to sort values (Id1, Id2, Id3, Id4) by descending using pandas, for ex. that's become

```
                  Ip    Id1    Id2  Id3  Id4
0         10.10.8.30  10782  18156  NaN  NaN
1       10.10.12.113  10398  18177  NaN  NaN
2        10.10.6.111  10496  18140  NaN  NaN
3         10.10.6.97  10870  18093  NaN  NaN
4         10.10.6.63  10848  18965  NaN  NaN
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Pandas then this would help [Pandas Dataframe Sort](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this :

```
from pandas import DataFrame

df = DataFrame(data)
sorted = df.sort(['Id1', 'Id2', 'Id3', 'Id4'], ascending=[0])
```

Comment: Hello @kolas can you please try this one.

Comment: sort don't work I used sort_values but it does not work correct

Comment: test = df.sort_values(['one'], ascending=[False])

Comment: like this you can change [0] to false.

Comment: Yes I use this sorted = df.sort_values(['Id1', 'Id2', 'Id3', 'Id4'], ascending=False), but values don't sorting correct. For ex. here is true (Ip)10.10.8.30  (id1)10782  (id2)18156  (id3)NaN  (id)NaN, because id1 < id2, but here )ip)10.10.12.48  (id1)18171  (id)10724  (id3)NaN  (id4)NaN, sort does not work, because id1 is not < id2

Comment: df.sort_values(by='Id1', 'Id2', 'Id3', 'Id4', ascending=False)

Comment: can you please use like this.

Comment: yes I'm using this sorted = df.sort_values(['Id1', 'Id2', 'Id3', 'Id4'], ascending=False) and have the same output

Comment: Can you please try like this df = df.sort_values(by=['c1','c2'], ascending=[False,True])

Comment: you can pass true false then it's work. because it's working for me.